# How to iterate through array of type Observable<Type[]> or filter this array which is already filled

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an object of type `Observable<Cat[]>` which is already having data, following is the type of test

```
export interface Cat {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    isActive: true
}
```

here is my code

```
data$= this.mycatservice.GetCatList(); 
const filterString = 'ar';
this.results = of(this.data$).pipe(map(data=>data.filter(user=>user.userFullName.startsWith(filterString))));
```

I call service on `OnInit` and get full list
later based on my requirement I need to set filtered data to `results`
I want to filter it and select records which has name start from 'ar' output must be only list of name.

**Note:** Above code not working

Comment: Do you need assistance filtering the Observable or getting names that start with `ar`? I suggest adding code to your question so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer where I am going wrong I need only name from above collection which startwith 'ar' or whatever require to pass as startwith

Comment: Question is not very clear. Please attempt a solution and state the problematic output.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I update my code is question itself, can you go through and suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per your requirement, I think you need to get one name column as output and need to apply filter on observable array, Here is solution I suggest you this will work as per your requirement:

```
dataFilter: string = 'test';
  //your observable data        
  let data = of ([{
          id: '1',
          name: 'myTest',
          description: 'desc1',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'Test1',
          description: 'desc11',
          isActive: true
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          name: 'test',
          description: 'desc12',
          isActive: false
        },
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'tEst3',
          description: 'desc3',
          isActive: true
        }
      ])
      .pipe(map((dt) => dt.filter(cat => cat.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(dataFilter.toLowerCase())).map(u => u.name)))
       .subscribe(x=>{
         console.log(x)
     });
```

The output in console will be
`['Test1', 'test', 'tEst3']`  as I am using `toLowerCase()` here that will ignore case, but based on your requirement you can edit it. I am using `of()` here as I need to fill the array but if you have already the array then you don't need to use `of()` function just use `this.data$.pipe()` it will resolve your problem.

Hit like if it resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Zen it is the solution I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map operator in a pipe to filter the corresponding elements before displaying it :
The Angular model :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map, of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  filter: string = 'test';

  //your observable data
  data = of([
    {text: 'test_1'},
    {text: 'not corresponding'},
    {text: 'test'},
  ])
  .pipe(
    map((data) => data.filter(row => row.text.startsWith(this.filter)))
  );
}
```

the view :

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of data | async">
  {{ item.text }}
</p>
```

Comment: not working on my problem, I am getting error
using following code let data = of(this.data$).pipe(map((dt)=>dt.filter(row=>row.name.startsWith(event.query))));  getting error  Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Cat[]>'

Comment: you don't have to use of,you already have an observable  , in my example I needed to create test datas , that's why I used of ,  just do this.data$.pipe() without using of and it will work

Comment: ok, plz let me also know how to select only 'name' from the given Observable<Cat[]>

Comment: array.filter(…).map(row=>row.name) so you have an observable of string[]